# How to get list of calendars from Google Apps?

Tags: python, calendar, google-apps

I just want to get list of calendares, their owners, and their free/busy state.

I've added Service Account according to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation), and I can get calendars from single user. But I want to do this domain-wide.

```
f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
                                            key,
                                            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                                            user_agent='bot',
                                            sub='john@example.cz')    #I want calendars from everyone
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
lists = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=None).execute(http=http)
pprint.pprint(lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to also use the Directory API within the Admin SDK to pull a list of all users within the domain as per [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users).

Comment: Ok, but if I do this for each user, it takes a bit over 1 second for each user. And if you have company with 400 employees, it takes 7 minutes to complete. Which is too much. Any idea how to make it faster?

Comment: Could you edit your first post so we could see how you've implemented this? A second per user seems way off as I've never seen more than a few ms.

Comment: I implemented it exactly as it's in the first post. Only difference is one added line, which asks for freebusy for the previously acquired list of calendars. So, just one more request/response.